# How to add a manifest file to a project in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, manifest

I am trying to add a manifest file to a project with Visual Studio 2010, so as to set the project to be compatible with Windows 7 and to disable the virtualization.

The problem is that in my Visual Studio 2010 there is no option "Application Manifest File" to choose when I want to add a new item.

I can generate a manifest file when building the project, as I set the property in the Linker to do so. But can I modify that file to add the compatibility property to it?

Is there some way to create the manifest file inside the project and then build it? Or can I set the compatibility property from the Properties dialog (manifest tool) itself?

Answer (score 14):

1. Create the manifest file you want.
2. Save it somewhere on your computer with a `.manifest` extension.
3. Right-click your project in Visual Studio, and select `Add > Existing Item...`
4. Browse to the manifest file and open it.
5. Build your project.

Comment: Verified now, worked for me: VS2017 / x64 build on Win10.
I'd like add my two cents:
6.  Using visual studio open the executable file, find the RT_MANIFEST resource, copy the contents to notepad,  double check it contains the snippet specified in you .manifest file.

Comment: Where's the trust? :P The mt shunted sections around- e.g. original had trustinfo after compatibility- now it's before. *Trust before Compatibility*.  (pearls before swine?)

Comment: @zhaorufei This is super hacky to just rip manifest out of .exe file, I like it!

Comment: Important (at least to me): The project must be X64 and not x86. With x86 the linker refused to open the exe ("LINK : fatal error LNK1104"). I lazy set up a test project and the defaults were 32-bit, so I lost a few hours research time and finally tried this switch: worked then finally.

Answer (score 5):

A method I use is to set the project properties / Manifest Tool / Input & Output / Embed Manifest" setting to "No". Then, in my RC file add this line: **CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "MyProject.exe.manifest"**