# Manifest for Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2010 C/C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-10, manifest

I have a sample console app in Visual Studio 2010 C/C++.  I am trying to Manifest it for Windows 10 as per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1). As instructed in other threads I did this:

- Saved the sample Manifest from the article into a file app.manifest
- Right clicked on the project and added app.manifest to the project
- Rebuilt the project

However I get error: failed to load and parse the manifest.

I even tried adding it instead as an additional manifest file with the same results.

The referenced article also says to add several variables to the sources file. However, there is no sources file as far as I can see.

Can I Manifest for Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2010? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: c tag removed, but remember your semicolons!

Comment: You don't need to target your application for Windows. Just use the modern version information functions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/version-helper-apis

Comment: @Alf - thanks for the link. I did see that, but there is no single API that gives you the OS version. And I'd still like to learn how to Manifest for Windows 10.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Without explicitly targeting application for Windows10 by including corresponding manifest entry those modern version information functions will return compatibility information.

Comment: @NeilWeicher: GetProductInfo  looks like a single API that does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample manifest file at that link is just that: a sample. It includes things like `name=SXS_ASSEMBLY_NAME`, which aren't even valid XML. It is not meant to be copy-pasted. If you want to use that example (you don't!), you at least need to put your actual application info in, including double quotes around the XML attribute values.

As for how to embed a manifest, see [How to add a manifest file to a project in visual studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504732/how-to-add-a-manifest-file-to-a-project-in-visual-studio-2010).

Comment: The thread you referenced was the exact one I took the instructions from. Ok, I filled in the variables but now get the following error: **"manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "compatibility" in namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"**.  I'm stumped.

Comment: @NeilWeicher Feel free to create a new question to ask about that.

Comment: should I delete this question first?

Comment: No, you shouldn't, unless you feel it was a bad question.

Comment: looks like two people don't like the question for some reason.