# Manifest for Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2010 C/C++ (part 2)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-10, manifest

I have a sample console app in Visual Studio 2010 C/C++.  I am trying to Manifest it for Windows 10 as per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504732/how-to-add-a-manifest-file-to-a-project-in-visual-studio-2010).  As instructed I did this:

- Saved the sample Manifest from the article into a file app.manifest
- Right clicked on the project and added app.manifest to the project
- Rebuilt the project

However I get this warning when building:

```
app.manifest : manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "compatibility" in namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1".
```

Can I Manifest for Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2010? Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is my full app.manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <assemblyIdentity 
    type="win32" 
    name="consoletest"
    version="1.0.0.0"
  />
  <description> my exe </description>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
            level="asInvoker"
            uiAccess="false"
        />   
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <!-- Windows 10 --> 
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application> 
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Just google the error message, first hit [takes you here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/2670561/fix-81010002-warning-message-when-you-rebuild-a-visual-c-project-in-vi).

Comment: Doh! Sorry to waste your time. I just took the MT.EXE from my VS 2017 install and now it builds ok. Thanks..