# IsWindows10OrGreater Always Returns False, even with Manifest File

Tags: c++, winapi, manifest, versioning

My C++ Win32/64 app does not recognize the manifest file. I keep receiving "Hello World!" and not "Hello World from Windows 10!"

I did research but I appear to be doing everything.

Linker Manifest Properties

[image: Linker Manifest Properties]

Linker Manifest Tool Properties

[image: Linker Manifest Tool Properties]

Output

[image: Output]

Solution Explorer

[image: Solution Explorer Showing Manifest File on C/C++ Win32/64 Project]

Source

```
int main()
{
    if (IsWindows10OrGreater())
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World from Windows 10!\n";

        int diskOs = GetOsDisk();
        EnumerateVolumes(diskOs);

    }
    else
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MidLevelConsole.exe"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
             If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
             requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
            Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
            compatibility.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on
           and is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements
           and Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
       DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
       to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
       also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. -->
  <!--
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
  -->

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!--
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
            />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  -->

</assembly>
```

Opening Up Exe in VS:

[image: EXE in VS]

Opening Exe as a Project/Solution in VS:

[image: Opening EXE as a Project/Solution in VS]

Notes:

1. The GetVersionInfoEx API is deprecated. Windows based applications are advised to use the IsWindows* functions, but that requires a manifest file. Even if it did not, which it does, I still would like to know what I am doing wrong.
2. I use Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise
3. My OS: Windows 10 Pro 1809 with all updates

EXE Link:

[EXE Download](https://www.sendspace.com/file/ef4xwm)

A few of the links that I looked at using SO and Google.

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/VersionHelpers/nf-versionhelpers-iswindows10orgreater)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504732/how-to-add-a-manifest-file-to-a-project-in-visual-studio-2010)
[3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-embed-a-manifest-inside-a-c-cpp-application?view=vs-2019)
[4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/manifest-generation-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Thoughts? No matter what I try, I get `IsWindows10OrGreater()` to always return false, signaling that there is no manifest file or an issue with it.

Comment: @YSC That solution uses GetVersionEx, which is deprecated. All new development are to use the IsWindows API set. The registry thing might work, but that is a hack, not a solution to why the manifest does not work.

Comment: are your *exe* really containing this manifest ?

Comment: begin from look  your exe in some PE viewer - are it really containing manifest resource (24.1)

Comment: @YSC I think the question good. I am not the person responsible for removing the GetVersionEx function(s) and telling users to use these alternate methods. I am not the one that made adding manifests in VS2017 to C++ apps a pain in the ass. Anyways, do you refer to the file version of `Kernel32.dll`. That might work, but that is a hack, not an answer to either question.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger - faster of all your exe not containing manifest. Best of all it would be if you upload your exe for look

Comment: You can simply open your EXE file with Visual Studio to see if manifest really is included. File > Open Project/Solution > Select your .exe file > OK. You should now see a treeview of the resources. There should be a branch "RT_MANIFEST" that has a child with ID of "1". Right click this item > Export to a file. Now verify that manifest is correct.

Comment: @RbMm I did not see any manifest for any exe either from PE or PE64, though I am not an expert with the tool.

Comment: @zett42 I opened the EXE as a file the other day to see nothing, so thank you for saying opening as a project/solution. That still showed nothing, screenshot added to question. I presume that means no manifest was added, though I should check another application that I know has a manifest to confirm.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger - this is reason why `IsWindows10OrGreater()` return false. if you say attach your test *exe* here - this will be just visible

Comment: @RbMm No clue how to attach exe to question. There is an attach picture, but not exe. I opened a WinForms exe which does have a manifest and that showed the same thing as this command line exe, nothing. Microsoft did not make looking at resource/manifest information obvious, at least to me.

Comment: There is something fishy about the two comboboxes at the top of the setting dialog.  They don't contain the word "Active", as expected to indicate that you are changing the settings of the config+platform you actually are going to build.  Not so obvious how this happened, since you do seem to have Debug x64 selected.  But regardless, since every build needs to use this manifest you favor selecting "All configurations" and "All platforms".  Double-check Build > Configuration Manager next to verify that you build what you expect.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger - your *MidLevelConsole.exe* not have resourse section at all. no have manifest

Comment: so really your problem - why *exe* which you build have no manifest. question not related to `VerifyVersionInfo` / `IsWindows10OrGreater`

Comment: @RbMm possibly. I just added a resource file along with a bitmap. I built the app and opened the x64 in VS bringing up Resource View (not obvious). I still did not see ANY resource, even the added bitmap. As I definitely added the bitmap, it should exist just like my manifest. A better restatement of the problem is why is VS2017 so buggie. Adding a resource or manifest by now should be as easy in C++ as in C# and viewing information easy too.

Comment: That's strange. I'm creating console applications every now and then, adding manifests and other resources works just fine. Normally I'm adding at least a version resource, but that shouldn't make a difference, as version resources are not mandatory. Have you verified with a "known-good" executable, that you can see its resources in VS?

Comment: @zett42 just did. I have a C# WinForms executable. I just opened the x64 debug, which contains many resources and a manifest. That is a production executable. Resource View and Solution Explorer views are empty. Manifest is fine. I have the executable launch as administration approval required, which it does.

Comment: Well, I just tried to open .exe file in VS2017 (15.9.5) and I'm not seeing resources too. Resource Hacker shows the resources though. I have also created a console application through the wizard, added your manifest file and your sample code. Works for me.

Comment: @zett42 if you send me your working project file keeping names as identical as possible, I can compare the project files and look for the differences to see what settings on my project are not set. There may be an easier way, but posting a sendspace.com link in the comment seems like a nice way to go.

Comment: @zett42 Also, what do you mean by creating a C++ > Windows Desktop > Windows Console Application through the wizard. Give steps.  There is no wizard. Might be easier if taking this particular thread to a chatroom before other people say to do that.

Comment: Here is my solution: https://uploadfiles.io/tysf27v2 You are right, there is no wizard. Just File > New Project > Windows Desktop > Windows Console Application.

Comment: The setting "Manifest File" under Linker / Manifest File is only used if the "Generate Manifiest" option is also turned on.

Instead, the setting you need to specify your custom manifest file is the "Additional Manifest Files" setting under Manifest Tool / Input and Output.

Comment: @JonathanPotter :-( I moved the manifest setting from Linker to Tools/InOut and still no change. VS2017 opening any EXE for me does not show any manifest, neither does PE.

Comment: If you zip your solution and upload it to dropbox or similar I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks, however I am close. I compared zett42 solution to my solution and saw differences. I removed the differences and my solution started to work. Tomorrow (Tuesday), I want to find out the exact deltas that caused the grief and I will let everyone know. Stay tuned. Actually, this question was quite interesting and I am learning a lot with it. I hope others feel the same way.

Comment: as variant you can write manifest file yourself (what you post under *Manifest:* section) and direct include it to *.rc* file (or include *.rc2* file to *.rc* and to *.rc2*) like `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "my_manifest_file"` and remove option embeded manifest - manifest will be exactly *my_manifest_file*

Comment: It's not immediately clear, what *problem* you are ultimately trying to solve. This question is really asking, why the proposed solution fails. But what are you going to do with the information returned by `IsWindows10OrGreater()`?

Comment: @zett42 Bingo. Thank you for the source. I narrowed down the lines in the project file to `<ManifestFile />` inside the `<Link>` node, which is part of the `<ItemDefinitionGroup...>`. I had to remove that. That empty ManifestFile node threw everything off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Required Settings From Default:**

Configuration Properties > Linker > Manifest File

- Generate Manifest: Yes (/MANIFEST)

Configuration Properties > Manifest Tool > Input and Output

- Additional Manifest Files: $(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).manifest
- Output Manifest File: $(TargetName).manifest

**My Problem After Setting the Required Settings:**

The problem was the empty `<ManifestFile />` node within the `<ItemDefintionGroup...>` node.

Good Project File Fragment 1:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
    <Manifest>
      <AdditionalManifestFiles>manifest.xml</AdditionalManifestFiles>
    </Manifest>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Bad Project File Fragment 1:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <ManifestFile>
      </ManifestFile>
    </Link>
    <Manifest>
      <AdditionalManifestFiles>$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).manifest</AdditionalManifestFiles>
      <OutputManifestFile>$(TargetName).manifest</OutputManifestFile>
    </Manifest>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

The meaningful line, which my tinkering with the settings created inadvertently was:

```
  <ManifestFile>
  </ManifestFile>
```

That is inside the `<Link>` ... `</Link>` node. Deleting the `Manifest File` node resolved the problem. I had to do that for each configuration and platform.

Good Project File Fragment 2:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest>true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Bad Project File Fragment 2:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest>true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
    <EmbedManifest />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Like before, I had to remove the empty `manfest` section, namely `<EmbedManifest />` from each of the Property Group platform/configuration sections.

I added and then removed items from these property groups. Visually, the change was nothing, adding and then removing, however Visual Studio 2017 leaves the sections as an empty group, which prevents the manifest from loading.

Here is the complete working project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>15.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{64BA277A-6ED7-445D-B807-A7DD6B8FE458}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>VersionHelpersTest</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest>true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest>true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest>true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
    <Manifest>
      <AdditionalManifestFiles>$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).manifest</AdditionalManifestFiles>
      <OutputManifestFile>$(TargetName).manifest</OutputManifestFile>
    </Manifest>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
    <Manifest>
      <AdditionalManifestFiles>$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).manifest</AdditionalManifestFiles>
      <OutputManifestFile>$(TargetName).manifest</OutputManifestFile>
    </Manifest>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
    <Manifest>
      <AdditionalManifestFiles>$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).manifest</AdditionalManifestFiles>
      <OutputManifestFile>$(TargetName).manifest</OutputManifestFile>
    </Manifest>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
    <Manifest>
      <AdditionalManifestFiles>$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).manifest</AdditionalManifestFiles>
      <OutputManifestFile>$(TargetName).manifest</OutputManifestFile>
    </Manifest>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="pch.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="pch.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="VersionHelpersTest.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

That to me is a HUGE bug in Visual Studio, and totally not obvious. Another bug is that by VS2019, manifests inside a C++ app should be as easy as it is with a C# application and come automatically.

Comment: I'm adding the manifest file "manually" into the .rc file via an `1                       RT_MANIFEST             "res\\manifest.xml"` thus avoiding all buggy and hard to understand VS manifest generation crap.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - agree. always do the same. only not direct to *.rc* but via *.rc2* included to *.rc* not under `APSTUDIO_INVOKED`.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler solution:

```
inline bool isWindows11OrGreater()
{
    NTSTATUS (NTAPI * RtlGetVersion)(PRTL_OSVERSIONINFOW lpVersionInformation) = nullptr;
    HMODULE ntdll = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll");
    if (ntdll == NULL)
        return false;
    *reinterpret_cast<FARPROC*>(&RtlGetVersion) = GetProcAddress(ntdll, "RtlGetVersion");
    if (RtlGetVersion == nullptr)
        return false;

    OSVERSIONINFOEX versionInfo{ sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX) };
    if (RtlGetVersion(reinterpret_cast<LPOSVERSIONINFO>(&versionInfo)) < 0)
        return false;

    if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion > HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10))
        return true;

    if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion == HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10))
    {
        if (versionInfo.dwMinorVersion > LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10))
            return true;

        if (versionInfo.dwMinorVersion == LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10) && versionInfo.dwBuildNumber >= 22000)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```